# Prestashop module page url rewrite in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

i have created a controller in prestashop module. my url is like this http://www.prestashop.com/module/homepageadvertise/brands/

i want my url should be like this

http://www.prestashop.com/brands/

How can i achieve it by changing the htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yau can change in BO > prefences > SEO & URL > just add new , in page you chose module, in Rewritten URL type brands

and save

[image]